# Most Flexible Open Office Word Document Format (Not MS Word) For Git Versioning and Collaboration

Tags: git, github, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I am looking to start a collaborative word document in Git, and want to know what is the best format?

**Some loose requirements I have for this document are**: potential to easily add some simple markup, like bold, italics, maybe some font sizes or highlighting (nothing too technical). Ability to work seamlessly in git without too many complicated commands, as not everybody on the project will be a git guru, or may even be first time users. Something that is light

I'm already biased against Microsoft Word because I don't want to pay for it, and it has a lot of the bells and whistles I don't need, and frankly find annoying.

I'm already leaning towards using OpenOffice Writer with ODF formatting. Has anybody done this, or have any suggestions on why this is not a good idea? There are a lot of formats to choose from, like this picture:[image]

That is sorta overwhelming.

My reasoning for using OpenOffice is that it's free, it can install on most computers, and it is open source. This project is open source as well, and it seems like using open source tools is true to the spirit.

I know this is not a discussion forum, and I truly am looking for a definitive answer on file type, or some suggestions from anybody who has experience versioning word / text documents in Git. It's totally out of the question to use SVN in this project, mainly because it sucks. Thanks!

updated: The idea would be to version this in **Github**

The project is about engineers, linguists, and other programmers who are interested in cleaning up, standardizing and overall improving the kind of language we use to refer to computer language concepts.

There is a great suggestion below about using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) like in Github README's, which sounds awesome to me, but I'm not sure if this would scare non-github, non computer tech savvy people away.

Comment: Personally, I think a wiki would fit your requirements better.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt yeah, i was thinking a wiki would be another option. which wiki would you recommend? i will update my initial post at the bottom to detail a little about the project.

Comment: You might find [this little trick](http://xcafebabe.blogspot.hu/2012/09/sexy-comparison-of-word-documents-with.html) interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a wiki at [wikispaces](http://www.wikispaces.com). I feel like it met all of my needs. I will summarize some of the pros and cons of using either.

Github pros:

- Awesome community and collaboration

Github cons:

- Not super easy to use (although that is debatable)

Wiki pros:

- Easy to use for all kinds of different people

Wiki cons:

- It's ugly, I don't like the versioning system, and the community
  seems dull.

**Ultimately I had to choose ease of use over all the cool features of Github.**

I should give credit to @Karl above.

I really appreciate all the help, and took a lot from this. Especially learned about some cool features of Github.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You probably already realize that source control mechanisms tend to be ill-suited for versioning documents *a la* Word.  What you may wish to consider instead, especially since you are using GitHub, is simple text files with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) formatting.  It's not difficult to learn, and GitHub will automatically display the formatting when displaying, say, README.md.

The document type you are using has little or nothing to do with the learning curve for using Git, which will be similar regardless of what you are versioning.

Comment: Actually, I guess I imagined that you said you were using GitHub, when you only mentioned it in your tags.  However, with an open source project, you may as well consider it since it is free for open source projects, is open-source itself, etc.

Comment: you're right, i'm using github and loving it. you're totally right, that's exactly my idea. I did think of the way README's are composed on github and that is really exactly what i'm looking for. the problem is that i didn't know if it was as robust, or easy to understand as simple word document. i'm thinking this document could reach hundreds of pages... i will try to find more info on README's and Markdown formatting, thanks for that!

Comment: could Markdown be easily written inside of a OpenOffice text / word doc. I may go with this solution if so.

Comment: [Apparently so](http://www.baryudin.com/blog/editing-markdown-or-txt-files-openoffice.html), with a little work.  Done correctly, no one would _have_ to use OpenOffice as a text editor, and I'd almost think it would be more convenient not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to stick with OpenOffice (other answers/comments seem to indicate that's not a hard requirement), recent versions of OO allow you to save in an uncompressed XML format (.fodt in this case) that actually works pretty well for storing in a VCS, although the files are considerably larger than the compressed format, the deltas for subsequent versions are reasonably close to the size of the actual changes to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is an open standard and it is being used by many big companies out there.

There is an excellent tool that your users can use to edit the markdown files:

http://markdownpad.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd say github uses [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org./quickref.html), which is a superset of markdown. I supports footnotes, tables, and other stuff standard markdown doesn't. As you might need one of those, consider setting up your local editors which support kramdown, or rather [the php extras kramdown implements](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open source document management systems that handle OoO documents of varying degrees of open-ness.

This has a list.

http://wiki.i-rs.ru/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Solutions#Content_.26_Document_Management_Systems.2C_Search_Technology

However I do think your suggestion of just uncompressing the OoO files and storing them in Git is quite elegant. I suspect it's been done, possibly as a plug-in. What would be nice is if said plug-in had a way to see commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

[gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) looks like another possible option, although i don't know much about it. it is a wiki built by github, surprised nobody mentioned this.